# Update multiple timestamp fileds Laravel ORM Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, orm, eloquent, laravel-5

For simple I have field `(timestamp) started_at`, `(int) duration` and I have rows with ids `[1, 2, 3]`. When I remove first object I want to update `started_at` field in all next rows (in my example are rows 2 and 3).

I tried to do something like this:

```
Model::where('id', '>', $myObject->id)
     ->update([
         'started_at' => DB::raw('started_at - ' . $myObject->duration),
     ]);
```

But this construction set my fields to `0000-00-00 00:00:00`. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is with your SQL syntax - you can't subtract periods like that - you must use [DATE_SUB function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub) or INTERVAL keyword (for MySQL)

**UPDATE:** You can also store timestamp in that column as a simple number. In that case arithmetic operations will work.

Comment: I know about `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` or something like that in MySQL, but I want to find a global solution for my problem ;)

Comment: Actually that could be a good option if you want to easily add/subtract intervals without using RDBMS-specific functions. Create timestamp in PHP, store it and then you will be able to perform mathematical operations with it.

Comment: I could store data in PHP variables, but for many data I have many updates :(

Comment: You must have understood me wrong. Define `started_at` as `INT` in your table. When you first insert record - generate timestamp in PHP and save to that field. Then construction you specified above will just work.

Comment: Ah, okay. I understand now :) maybe it is not a wrong solution. Thank You :)

Comment: You've probably used `DATETIME` field that is specific for storing date/time object in DB. But you should probably use simple `INT` instead to store timestamp and be able to add/subtract to/from it.